# Unrefined symbol error in xcode, due to deconstructor in C++

Tags: c++, xcode, class

I'm trying to make a deconstructor in C++ on xCode but I'm getting an error which is exactly as follows: `Undefined symbol: Shader::Shader()` and I think it's because it isnt recognising my deconstructor `~Shader()`.

The full error message is:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
    "Shader::Shader()", referenced from:
        init() in example.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I've watched some videos on deconstructors but none of them seem to be using xcode or have this problem. So I'm not sure how to get rid of this error.

Here is the code used:

Shader.h

```
class Shader {
public:
    Shader(void);
    ~Shader();
}
```

Shader.cpp

```
Shader::Shader(void)
{
    m_name = "";
    m_vertexShader = 0;
    m_fragmentShader = 0;
    m_programObject = 0;
}

Shader::~Shader()
{
    glUseProgram(0);
    glDeleteShader(m_vertexShader);
    glDeleteShader(m_fragmentShader);
    glDeleteProgram(m_programObject);
}
```

init() function in example.cpp:

```
void init()
{
    glClearColor(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);                      

    myShader = new Shader;
    if(!myShader->load("Basic", "glslfiles/basic.vert", "glslfiles/basic.frag")) {
        cout << "failed to load shader" << endl;
    }                                               
    createGeometry();   
}
```

Comment: `Undefined symbol: Shader::Shader()` - that's not a missing destructor; it's a missing **constructor**. So.. where is your constructor ? Your class def declared that one exists; but there is none in your cpp file; only a destructor. As always, a proper [mcve] would be appropriate, as clearly you've left out a *lot* of code, intentionally or otherwise.

Comment: I have the constructor already just forgot to add it to the question because I was focused on the destructor, and i thought it was the destructor causing issue because when I removed it, it wouldn't give me the error, but doing that now doesn't change anything at all anymore so I'm just confused